# Convert any title to url slug and back from url slug to title

Tags: php, string, url-encoding, slug

I want to convert any title e.g. of a blog entry to a user friendly url. I used [rawurlencode()](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode) to do that but it gives me a lot of strange strings like `%s`.

The algorithm should consider german chars like Ö, Ä, etc. I want to make a url from title and be able to get the title by decoding the url.

I tried some of this code: http://pastebin.com/L1SwESBn that is provided in some other questions but it seems to be one way.

E.g. `HÖRZU.de -> hoerzu-de -> HÖRZU.de`

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to create slugs, but from experience i can tell you the decode possibilities are limited.

Comment: you can't decode it. it's one-way

Comment: You can't decode it. How would you know if the right solution is HORZU.DE, Hörzu.de, HÖRZU.DE, Hòrzu.de, Hörzü.de or any other of the millions of different combinations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to create slugs, but from experience i can tell you the decode possibilities are limited. For example "Foo - Bar" will become "foo-bar" so how do you then can possibly know that it wasn't "foo bar" or "foo-bar" all along?

Or how about chars that you don't want in your slug and also have no representation for like " ` "? 
So you can ether use a 1 to 1 converstion like `rawurlencode()` or you can create a Slug, here is an example for a function - but as i said, no reliable decoding possible - its just in its nature since you have to throw away Information.

```
function sanitizeStringForUrl($string){
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = html_entity_decode($string);
    $string = str_replace(array('ä','ü','ö','ß'),array('ae','ue','oe','ss'),$string);
    $string = preg_replace('#[^\w\säüöß]#',null,$string);
    $string = preg_replace('#[\s]{2,}#',' ',$string);
    $string = str_replace(array(' '),array('-'),$string);
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function url_title($str, $separator = 'dash', $lowercase = FALSE)
 {
  if ($separator == 'dash')
  {
   $search  = '_';
   $replace = '-';
  }
  else
  {
   $search  = '-';
   $replace = '_';
  }

  $trans = array(
      '&\#\d+?;'    => '',
      '&\S+?;'    => '',
      '\s+'     => $replace,
      '[^a-z0-9\-\._]'  => '',
      $replace.'+'   => $replace,
      $replace.'$'   => $replace,
      '^'.$replace   => $replace,
      '\.+$'     => ''
       );

  $str = strip_tags($str);

  foreach ($trans as $key => $val)
  {
   $str = preg_replace("#".$key."#i", $val, $str);
  }

  if ($lowercase === TRUE)
  {
   $str = strtolower($str);
  }

  return trim(stripslashes($str));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way I think is using a Behat\Transliterator\Transliterator.

I need to extends this class by your class because it is an Abstract, some like this:

```
<?php
use Behat\Transliterator\Transliterator;

class Urlizer extends Transliterator
{
}
```

And then, just use it:

```
$text = "Master Ápiu";
$urlizer = new Urlizer();
$slug = $urlizer->transliterate($slug, "-");
echo $slug; // master-apiu
```

Of course you should put this things in your composer as well.

```
composer require behat/transliterator
```

More info here https://github.com/Behat/Transliterator

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question: how can you decode a slug back to original form?

Answer (score 0):

there is no reliable way to 'decode' the slug back to its original form. the best solution here would be to database the slug and its original.